# Android RadioGroup hold data

Tags: android, radio-button, sharedpreferences

This is my first android protject which i made for my school.

We are devolping an app that's going to hold 10 questions with 4 possible answers in form of RadioButtons pr. question.

The .Java pages look like this

```
   package odense.skp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Question1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1);
    }

    public void Nextpage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Question2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1);
        ((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group))
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener((OnCheckedChangeListener)    this);
    }

    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId) {
        case R.id.first_radio_button:
            break;
        case R.id.second_radio_button:
            break;
        case R.id.third_radio_button:
            break;
        case R.id.fourth_radio_button:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.question1, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and the XML for that .java looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Question2" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnN"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="Nextpage"
    android:text="@string/Next" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/Spg1" >
</TextView>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radio_group"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/first_radio_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:paddingLeft="40dip"
        android:text="@string/Ans1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/second_radio_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:paddingLeft="40dip"
        android:text="@string/Ans2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/third_radio_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:paddingLeft="40dip"
        android:text="@string/Ans3" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/fourth_radio_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:paddingLeft="40dip"
        android:text="@string/Ans4" >
    </RadioButton>
</RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to be able to store the data given in the diffrent activities until finally sending them on to a Database (MySQL) if you got any ideas on how this might be possible, please respond

- Regards Jonas Quist

  !!UPDATE!! If we forget about the SQL for now, is there anyways that i can make the application hold the input given to the radioGroup even tho i go to the next question (the next activity) So that after answering all 10 questions i can have a send button that sends all the data stored within the app?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, I'm not sure how much you know about database input... a good start would be [here](http://www.example8.com/category/view/id/15568) or [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html). Once you've set up your database helper, you can call that on checkedChanged in your radio group:

```
case R.id.first_radio_button:

DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        database = helper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(theQuery, null);

        ArrayList<String> listInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
listInfo.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("firstColumn")));
listInfo.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("otherColumn")));
        }

        cursor.close();
        database.close();
        break;
```

Better yet, set up your database input as a function, then call that in your switch.

Comment: I don't know alot about databases no, and I will look up those links you send me and set up a database helper.

Comment: Hate to sound like other posters here, but we're point-hungry...if you found the answer useful, please up-vote.

Comment: Really wish i could m8 :P but i dont have enough "reputation" to be able to :P